# How to get the top element per group with multiple columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the use-case shown below. Basically I have a data frame with three columns. I want to group by two columns `(c1,c2)` and sum the third one `c3`. Then I want to pick only the top 1 `c1` with maximum `c3` (among all `c2`) i.e. sorting would be unnecessary since I'm only interested in the max.

```
library(plyr)

df <- data.frame(c1=c('a','a','a','b','b','c'),c2=c('x','y','y','x','y','x'),c3=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
df
  c1 c2 c3
1  a  x  1
2  a  y  2
3  a  y  3
4  b  x  4
5  b  y  5
6  c  x  6

sel <- plyr::ddply(df, c('c1','c2'), plyr::summarize,c3=sum(c3))
sel[with(sel, order(c1,-c3)),]
  c1 c2 c3
2  a  y  5 <<< this one highest c3 for (c1,c2) combination
1  a  x  1
4  b  y  5 <<< this one highest c3 for (c1,c2) combination
3  b  x  4
5  c  x  6 <<< this one highest c3 for (c1,c2) combination
```

I could do this in a loop but I'm wondering how it can be done in a vector fashion or using a high-level function.

Comment: After summing c3 by groups of c1+c2, you'll only have 1 row per group of c1+c2.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. I edited the question. I'm interested in the `c1` with maximum `c3` across all `c2`s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a base R approach:

```
df2 <- aggregate(c3~c1+c2, df, sum)
subset(df2[order(-df2$c3),], !duplicated(c1))
#  c1 c2 c3
#3  c  x  6
#4  a  y  5
#5  b  y  5
```

Comment: Nice I like it because is simple and uses only base ... However, I am concerned about the `!duplicate` bit because there is no specification contract that it has to pick the first one found ... it is an implementation choice that if changes, then the solution would break or?

Comment: @GiovanniAzua, not sure I understand your question. This approach orders by decreasing c3-sum and then picks the first row (=max c3-row) per c1. If you want to do something else later, the approach also has to change, obviously

Answer (score 3):

Another solution from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(c1, c2) %>%
  summarise(c3 = sum(c3)) %>%
  filter(c3 == max(c3))

df2
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   c1 [3]
      c1     c2    c3
  <fctr> <fctr> <dbl>
1      a      y     5
2      b      y     5
3      c      x     6
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(c3 = sum(c3)) , .(c1, c2)][, .SD[which.max(c3)], .(c1)]
#   c1 c2 c3
#1:  a  y  5
#2:  b  y  5
#3:  c  x  6
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(c1, c2) %>% 
  summarise(c3 = sum(c3)) %>% 
  top_n(1, c3)
```

Or the last line can be `slice(which.max(c3))`, which will guarantee a single row.